# OpenCV libopencv_core.so.2.4.1 File Not Found

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, cmake

I am trying to setup OpenCV v2.4.1 with FFMPEG v0.11 support on Scientific Linux SL release 5.0 (Boron), and I am running into a problem with a missing file that seems completely undocumented. The error I am getting is as follows:

```
-- Install configuration: "Release"

-- Up-to-date: /home/s18/s1138832/OpenCV/include/opencv/cv.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/s18/s1138832/OpenCV/include/opencv/cxmisc.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/s18/s1138832/OpenCV/include/opencv/cvwimage.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/s18/s1138832/OpenCV/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp
CMake Error at modules/core/cmake_install.cmake:63 (FILE):
file INSTALL cannot find file
  "/home/s18/s1138832/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.1" to install.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/cmake_install.cmake:57 (INCLUDE)
  cmake_install.cmake:56 (INCLUDE)
```

I honestly don't know where to begin troubleshooting this at this point. I successfully installed without ffmpeg a few days ago, but now I can't even install with ffmpeg support set to off.

The files that link to the missing library are:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 s1138832 s18      21 Jun 17 18:26 libopencv_core.so ->    libopencv_core.so.2.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 s1138832 s18      23 Jun 17 18:26 libopencv_core.so.2.4 -> libopencv_core.so.2.4.1
```

Any advice or prods in the right direction would be much appreciated. I would also be happy to provide more info on whatever interesting details I may have omitted.

UPDATES: This website seems to have the same error, but I can't read it and translations patchy - http://www.opencv.org.cn/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15664 ( http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opencv.org.cn%2Fforum%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D1%26t%3D15664&act=url )

libopencv_core.so.2.4.1 exists after "make", but "make install" deletes it somehow. I copied it and added it again, but it didn't change anything

Comment: It's not quite clear in the question, but I suspect that you're doing `make install` without doing `make` to build the libraries first. The core library is missing since it is not yet built.

Comment: Thanks deepak, but I am definitely doing ccmake for config, then make; make install

Comment: Probably only vaguely helpful, but I trust you deleted your build folder and re-built from scratch? Even with make clean I've had cmake mess up its CMakeCache.txt sometimes; nothing for it but rm -rf build...

Comment: Thanks for the response Doug, unfortunately I have tried this as well with no success. I appreciate the brainstorming though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, it was something very simple! I had my CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX set to "/foo" and I was configuring and building from "/foo" - when I configured from "/foo/temp" everything went swimmingly.

I guess the make install step tries to copy your built files to the install prefix path, and deletes the originals. Obviously this could cause some problems. Works like a charm now.

Thanks to everyone who made suggestions!